# Button went invisible in jellybean

Tags: android, android-layout

My app works fine through the jellybean update, except that the login button is invisible... clickable.. but you just can't see it.

here's the button code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/signin"
        android:text="" />
```

I don't know if there's some new way we are supposed to do button images or something that I just missed out on hearing.

Comment: Try removing `android:background="@drawable/signin"`, see if that changes things.

Comment: @gjj yes.. the button shows up just fine without that line (of course I added ipsum to the android:text)

Comment: how many drawable folders do you have? I mean e.g drawable/drawable-hdpi/drawable-ldpi/drawable-v14/drawable-large/ etc...  please list all of them. I think the problem is from resources that is not same in your Froyo device and JB device.

Comment: @yrajabi I have
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
I have always kept one resolution of it in just drawable.. because that's all it really needs.

Comment: @yrajabi I just added it to all of the them... no change.

Comment: ok, when you touch the invisible button and hold, does it still remains invisible or shows some feedback?!

Comment: @yrajabi I just changed everything to "ImageButton" instead of "Button"... image doesn't show up, but a blank button does now show up.. the problem lies in accessing the drawable it would seem.. I just can't figure out why JB would break this!?

Comment: Did you use permanent marker? Maybe someone ate it ;)

Comment: @Doomsknight  
JellyBean eats GIFS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the format of the image from gif to png... problem fixed.
This might be good for someone else out there to know!

(I also renamed it, FYI)

Comment: Interesting... I thought gif's weren't supposed to work at all (there is a workaround for them). PNG's are 100% the way to go.

Comment: Oh, GIF?!!! they wasn't good for anything but the web in 1990's and earlier 2000's. I thought about anything except that you use a GIF in your app! :)

Answer (score -1):

`drawable/signin` is transparent.

Comment: if you intended a "?" at the end... the answer is yes.. froyo, and ICS view "@drawable/signin" just fine... JB.. it's transparent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).